# Two ngModel in one input

Tags: angular, forms, ngmodel

I have a input select and I would like to put 2 ngModel.

ngModel priceMin.
ngModel priceMax.

Is it possible to do it?  or Have I to use ngChange?

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Precio</label>
          <select [(ngModel)]="searchAside.priceMin" [(ngModel)]="searchAside.priceMax" name="price" class="custom-select">
              <option [value]="undefined">Todos</option>
              <option [value]="10000">€0 - €10.000</option>
              <option [value]="25000">€25.000 - €50.000</option>
              <option [value]="50000">€50.000 - €100.000</option>
              <option [value]="100000">€100.000 - €250.000</option>
              <option [value]="250000">€250.000 - €500.000</option>
              <option [value]="500000">€500.000 +</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Precio</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="searchAside.priceMin (change)="onChange($event.target.value)" name="price" class="custom-select">
          <option [value]="undefined">Todos</option>
          <option [value]="10000">€0 - €10.000</option>
          <option [value]="25000">€25.000 - €50.000</option>
          <option [value]="50000">€50.000 - €100.000</option>
          <option [value]="100000">€100.000 - €250.000</option>
          <option [value]="250000">€250.000 - €500.000</option>
          <option [value]="500000">€500.000 +</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**TS**

```
onChange(value) {
   this.searchAside['priceMax'] = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think that this is possible, but if you really need this there are workaround depending on what you want to do.